# which firefox is compatible with selenium 2.49 or 2.48.2?

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I am using firefox on RHEL 6.4 for selenium script. For this I had used selenium 2.48.2, 2.49 version but I could not find compatible version of firefox with these selenium version. I am using Xming for triggering the firefox from linux on windows. please can anyone provide some help to which firefox driver is compatible with selenium 2.49 or 2.48.2. I had already tried firefox 39,41,43,44 version but I am getting the following exception -

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
iding the updated system add-ons.
1456292657904   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering startup change 'installed' for fxdriver@googlecode.com
1456292657904   addons.xpi-utils        DEBUG   Make addon app-profile:fxdriver@googlecode.com visible
1456292657905   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1456292657905   addons.xpi-utils        DEBUG   Make addon app-global:{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} visible
1456292657905   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1456292657906   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Updating XPIState for `{"id":"fxdriver@googlecode.com","syncGUID":"RdhxVFQ80wzQ","location":"app-profile","version":"2.48.0","type":"extension","internalName":null,"updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Firefox WebDriver","description":"WebDriver implementation for Firefox","creator":"Simon Stewart","homepageURL":null},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"/tmp/anonymous3945461434748043456webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com","installDate":1456292633000,"updateDate":1456292633000,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"bootstrap":false,"size":3213569,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":true,"hasBinaryComponents":true,"strictCompatibility":false,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"3.0","maxVersion":"45.0"}],"targetPlatforms":[{"os":"Darwin","abi":null},{"os":"SunOS","abi":null},{"os":"FreeBSD","abi":null},{"os":"OpenBSD","abi":null},{"os":"WINNT","abi":"x86-msvc"},{"os":"Linux","abi":null}],"multiprocessCompatible":false,"signedState":0}
1456292657907   addons.xpi      DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of fxdriver@googlecode.com
1456292657909   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Updating XPIState for {"id":"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","syncGUID":"B6gLC6ZQUiLs","location":"app-global","version":"43.0","type":"theme","internalName":"classic/1.0","updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Default","description":"The default theme.","creator":"Mozilla","homepageURL":null,"contributors":["Mozilla Contributors"]},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"/opt/firefox/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","installDate":1449604917000,"updateDate":1449604917000,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"skinnable":true,"size":5022,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":true,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"43.0","maxVersion":"43.0"}],"targetPlatforms":[]}
1456292657910   addons.xpi      DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
1456292657911   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1456292657911   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
1456292657911   addons.xpi-utils        DEBUG   Updating add-on states
1456292657912   addons.xpi-utils        DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
1456292657923   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1456292657924   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1456292657924   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1456292657924   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1456292657925   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1456292657926   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1456292657932   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1456292657932   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1456292657932   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1456292657933   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1456292657933   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1456292657934   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:123)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:117)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:207)`
```

Also I could find that selenium 2.41 is working with firefox 30 version, but I want to use selenium 2.49 so I want compatible firefox for 2.49 version.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the change log : https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/CHANGELOG

Firefox v41 should work fine with selenium 2.49

Comment: I had already preffered this document CHANGELOG, and tried v41 but still  issue persist.

Comment: Ok. can you check once whether the version of FF is still the same? Typically it updates automatically, unless the option is not turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox v42 will work fine. I used v42 for both versions

Comment: i had tried this with 2.49 but still getting the same exception

Answer (score 0):

It says in the [CHANGELOG notes](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/CHANGELOG) for version 2.48 that you MUST USE no later version than Firefox `31.6.0 ESR` if your intent is to use any of the native event calls, such as `driver.navigate()`  or `element.click()` .

If you open a browser and use synthetic non-native events with Javascript to navigate the url and/or to click on stuff, then yes, all later versions of Firefox will work for you.